# Can't Get The Php Variable To My Node Js using npm: exec-php module

Tags: javascript, php, node.js

Following is the Server.js File, here I am Fetching The Details From Table which working Good. I need to Get a Variable From k.php which is in the Same Folder.Iam using npm exec-php module to get the Values From Php File. But The Variable is Showing Undefined.

```
   var app = require('http').createServer(handler),
    io = require('socket.io').listen(app),
     fs = require('fs'),
      express=require('express'),
       session=require('express-session'),
     mysql = require('mysql'),
      execPhp = require('exec-php'),
      connectionsArray = [],
    connection = mysql.createConnection({
     host: 'localhost',
    user: 'root',
     password: '',
        database: 'test',
        port: 3306
       }),
       POLLING_INTERVAL = 3000,
      pollingTimer;






     // If there is an error connecting to the database
      connection.connect(function(err) {
        // connected! (unless `err` is set)
        if (err) {
       console.log(err);
       }
       });

      // creating the server ( localhost:8000 )
     app.listen(8000);

     // on server started we can load our client.html page
      function handler(req, res) {
          fs.readFile(__dirname + '/client.php', function(err, data) {
         if (err) {
          console.log(err);
          res.writeHead(500);
          return res.end('Error loading client.php');
        }
         res.writeHead(200);
         res.end(data);
        });
         }





     execPhp('k.php', function(error, php, outprint){
       // Here I expected The outprint Will be 'One' but it print undefined
         console.log(outprint);
           php.my_function(1, 2, function(err, result, output, printed){
       //this my_function is also showing Error
          });
        });


           var pollingLoop = function() {



        // Doing the database query
    var query = connection.query('SELECT * FROM users where user_id=1'),
       users = []; // this array will contain the result of our db query

    // setting the query listeners
         query
         .on('error', function(err) {
          // Handle error, and 'end' event will be emitted after this as well
           console.log(err);
         updateSockets(err);
        })
        .on('result', function(user) {
      // it fills our array looping on each user row inside the db
       users.push(user);
      })
       .on('end', function() {
    // loop on itself only if there are sockets still connected
        if (connectionsArray.length) {

          pollingTimer = setTimeout(pollingLoop, POLLING_INTERVAL);

          updateSockets({
            users: users
         });
        } else {

          console.log('The server timer was stopped because there are no more socket connections on the app')

         }
      });
   };


      // creating a new websocket to keep the content updated without any AJAX request
      io.sockets.on('connection', function(socket) {

       console.log('Number of connections:' + connectionsArray.length);
      // starting the loop only if at least there is one user connected
      if (!connectionsArray.length) {
         pollingLoop();
       }

      socket.on('disconnect', function() {
        var socketIndex = connectionsArray.indexOf(socket);
         console.log('socketID = %s got disconnected', socketIndex);
       if (~socketIndex) {
        connectionsArray.splice(socketIndex, 1);
      }
       });

       console.log('A new socket is connected!');
       connectionsArray.push(socket);

    });

     var updateSockets = function(data) {
        // adding the time of the last update
       data.time = new Date();
         console.log('Pushing new data to the clients connected (                      connections amount = %s ) - %s', connectionsArray.length , data.time);
       // sending new data to all the sockets connected
      connectionsArray.forEach(function(tmpSocket) {
tmpSocket.volatile.emit('notification', data);
      });
    };

      console.log('Please use your browser to navigate to http://localhost:8000');
```

the main Problem is in these Lines

```
       execPhp('k.php', function(error, php, outprint){
       // Here I expected The outprint Will be 'One' but it print undefined
         console.log(outprint);
           php.my_function(1, 2, function(err, result, output, printed){
       //this my_function is also showing Error
          });
        });
```

The Following is k.php in the same folder

```
           <?php




         echo "One";
        function my_function($arg1, $arg2){
            echo "Two";
           return $arg1 + $arg2;
         }



          ?>
```

This is the Error

[image: Error image]

Comment: In `execPhp('k.php', function(error, php, outprint){` do you check if there is actually an error and that is why `php` is undefiend?

Comment: Have you checked whether there are errors in the error variable? seems like execPhp could not load the php file propely, maybe because of execution rights?

Comment: it Dsiplaying Undefiined in the above Picture. i Found this Code From [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/exec-php)

Comment: I don't  know why my variable 'php' is undefined